# How do I introduce my content script into a web worker?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a web worker and I want to inject my content script into it

Currently my manifest looks like

```js
{
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "name" : "",
  "description" : "",
  "author" : "",
  "devtools_page" : "devtools/index.html",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "match_about_blank" : true,
      "js": ["content/index.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ]
}
```

and my content script looks like

```js
console.log('Hello World')
```

It runs on the top level page however it does not run inside my Web Worker

Comment: You can't do that. Content scripts runs only in web pages.

Comment: It feels like the correct way to communicate with nested entities (iframe, web workers, service workers) is to include a script internally which has them (post)message the main page running the extension.

Comment: Yes, you can use the standard means of communication.